# grid height issue when shown inside a window

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui

I have an issue with kendo grid i have a `window` and inside the window there is a `tabstrip` the content of the tab is two grid which are shown in tab1 and tab2 respectively ,also the window is invisible at first.

My problem is the `grid in the second tab height` exceeds the original grid-content height.
i have recreated the problem in jsfiddle [clickhere](http://jsfiddle.net/4663R/3/).I think someone can help me.

Comment: Why do you specify the height of the grid on it's definition? Did you try removing the `height: 500` option in the grids? You should probably control the height of the grid using `pageSize` and not `height`.

Comment: @OnaBai uff am sorry giving pageSize restrict the number of rows fetched from database ,but here client want to show all data but with overflow as scroll.do you have a solution ?

Comment: Arun, I need your help understanding the final goal. Lets see if I correctly understood... You want a grid that shows all results **not** using paging but scrolling. **But** this grid is inside a tabstrip tab (that happens to be inside a window) so it should not overflow its container (the tabstrip tab). Is that correct?

Comment: @OnaBai exactly sir ,but there is also one condition am loading data from server so i dont want same read to happen multiple time also.i think you got me.

Comment: That means that translates into you don't want `virtualScroll`. Ok! let me see what I can find in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the result as described in above comment:

> You want a grid that shows all results not using paging but scrolling. But this grid is inside a tabstrip tab (that happens to be inside a window) so it should not overflow its container (the tabstrip tab)

You should:

1. As far as I know, `height` is not a valid option of `kendoTabStrip`, you can remove it.
2. You don't want paging but bring all results from the server and then scroll. So you need to remove `pageable: ...` from your `Grid` initialization as well as `pageSize: 10` from the `DataSource` initialization.
3. After the creating the grid, you should remove a `height` styling that Kendo UI introduced since it is not correctly calculated (!?) by doing `$("#grid2").css("height","");`. This seems to me a little tricky but I couldn't get it running otherwise.
4. You should reduce the height of the grid a little otherwise it doesn't fit in the window. I changed it to 450.

In the following [modification of your example](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/4663R/6/) I did this modifications for `grid2` (**only** for grid2).

Comment: $("#grid2").css("height",""); this was the thing that i was missing .thanks sir. but kendo is not able to calculate the height of hidden elements i suppose.?

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your jsfiddle and found that

```
<div id="tabStrip">
    <ul>
        <li>First tab</li>
        <li>Second tab</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="grid1"></div>
    <div id="grid2">Second tab content</div>
</div>
```

in above code `<div id="grid2">Second tab content</div>` is creating height issue for second tab.

You can remove that text of `div` and try.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4663R/2/)

---

**Change**

I have made some changes to your code please see the bellow jsFiddle

**Fiddle**[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4663R/4/)

**Updated *[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4663R/5/)* as per your comment**

Comment: actually that wasn't my problem that text came out of mistake can you check the fiddle again i have updated. i will link here also http://jsfiddle.net/4663R/3/ ,you can see the height of both the grid now overflows

Comment: I found some problem with tabStrip loading and grid loading in your code tabstrip is loading before grid that may cause the problem. See changes above.

Comment: but i want the grid to be shown only on button click, that is at first grid is hidden

Comment: i found your solution but the problem is am using server data .and whenever i click on a tab it calls read of grid which is bad for performance .i appreciate your follow up and hardwork

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and solve by set the height of .k-grid-content in dataBound event

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid(
{
    dataBound: function()
    {
        $('#grid .k-grid-content').height(349);
    }
});
```

check jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4663R/54/)

Answer (score 0):

Grid height issue inside a window or tabstrip (other than active tab).
Actually these issue comes when we load the content partially or through ajax.

**Solution 1:** Working for me
- **Set a max-height** to the grid content container using CSS and **remove height** while binding grid. Hence when the grid content is larger than this height the scroller will be enabled. I have done as below.

CSS:

```
    #gridTasks .k-grid-content {
            max-height: 300px;
        }
```

javascript:

```
    //prepare datasource available for grid
                var taskDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    serverSorting: true,
                    pageSize: 10,
                    schema: {
                        data: "Data",
                        total: "Total",
                        model: { // define the model of the data source. Required for validation and property types.
                            id: "MemberID",
                            fields: {
                                MemberID: { type: "number", editable: false },
                                TaskName: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/MemberManagement/GetTasksList",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            type: "POST" //use HTTP POST request as by default GET is not allowed by ASP.NET MVC
                        },
                        parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                            if (operation == "read") {
                                return JSON.stringify(data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

    //bind grid
    $("#gridTasks").kendoGrid({
                 // height: 300, // remove this line ***
                    columns: [                
                        { field: "MemberID", title: "Member ID", width: 60, groupable: false, hidden: true },
                        { field: "TaskName", title: "Task Name", width: 100 , groupable: false }
                    ],
                    pageable: {
                        refresh: true,
                        pageSize: 10,
                        pageSizes: [10, 20, 50, 100],
                        buttonCount: 5,
                        messages: {
                            empty: "No Records Found.",
                            display: "{0}-{1} of {2}"
                        }
                    },
                    sortable: true,
                    selectable: "multiple",
                    scrollable: true,
                    filterable: true,
                    groupable: true,
                    dataSource: taskDataSource
                });
```

**Solution 2:** Also working for me. 
- Change the **k-grid-content** height on dataBound
javascript:

```
    dataBound: function() {
                 $('#gridTasks .k-grid-content').height(300);
              }
```